# How can I control the title and summary for comments posted to the user's wall, in a dynamically generated page?

Tags: comments, facebook-comments

I have many dynamically generated pages, made by the same PHP file, and I'd like the comments that are being submitted to the user's wall have a different title and summary, considering the page they were sent from. Do I need to dynamically generate the meta tags, or is there a way to embed the title and summary in the comments widget script itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do the first thing...dynamically generate the og tag in the head of the document.  They must be set that way when sending the HTML response to the browser. They cannot be successfully updated clientside as Facebook linter only looks at the response stream.